# Building a switch user tool: How to gain root permissions without dependencies

Tags: linux, chmod

I've been trying to make my own sudo program in Python, but I don't want to have any dependencies (like su or pkexec). How would I gain root access? Ideas:

1. Have the file always have root access (with chmod +[smth])
2. Somehow login as root (maybe with subprocess)
3. Use something built in (kind of a low-level dependency) and pass it the root password.

How would I do any of these or is there a different way? Or is Python even low level enough to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "switch user tool"? Are you just recreating `sudo` as an exercise? Traditionally switching to another user is handled on the shell with the user explicitly asking for something to be run by that user. Obfuscating this is a bit weird to do in a Unix-like environment.

Comment: @BrianReading Yes, I'm pretty much just recreating sudo in Python.

Comment: Are you looking to utilize the "sudoers" system already in place? or did you want to create a brand new system?

Comment: @BrianReading I'd like to create a brand new system, hence no dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a project and the goal is only to not have sudo dependencies while having root access, there are some [sudo alternatives](https://www.sudo.ws/docs/alternatives/). Use at your own risk, I have no experience with these. Also, I don't see pkexec or su being dependencies on the Arch or Ubuntu packages sites, but on Arch you can always force remove packages without removing any dependencies by using `sudo pacman -Rdd package_name`.

Comment: I didn't realize su wasn't a depedency. I'll use that. Out of curiosity, is there a way to not use su or sudo alternatives?